# Admin panel fatal error in helper data in magento

Tags: php, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

In Magento, when I'm uninstalling an automated remainder extension, it did not uninstall. I delete maintenance.log file in my site and when i return to Admin panel it shows the Fatal error:

> Class 'HZ_Reminder_Helper_Data' not found.

I did not change the code. How to solve this error?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is how easy we can uninstall module without Magento connect manager. This method might be useful if we are unable to delete some module through Magento web interface for some reason.

First you go to `app/etc/modules/` directory. If you will check this directory you will find `HZ_Reminder.xml` If there is file remove or disable it.

Then remove the following directory manually app/code/community/HZ/Reminder

`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/reminder.xml`
`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/reminder/reminder.phtml`
`app/locale/en_US/template/email/reminder/subscriber_reminder.html`